# udev rule for bluetooth device Logitech

Tags: linux, keyboard, monitoring, bluetooth, ude

I want to write udev rule for a Logitec Bluetooth. My keyboard and mouse connect to PC as one Bluetooth device.

When I monitor udev, I see there are separate events for keyboard and mouse. I want to allow mouse usage but not keyboard. If I ignore the device, I can't use the mouse. How can I achieve this? Can I ignore the keyboard event?

**Mouse event**

```
UDEV  [325.554801] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.2/4-1.2:1.0/input/input15 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.2/4-1.2:1.0/input/input15
EV=17
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=USB_Receiver
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Receiver
ID_MODEL_ID=c52f
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_2_1_0
ID_REVISION=3000
ID_SERIAL=Logitech_USB_Receiver
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030102:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
KEY=ffff0000 0 0 0 0
MODALIAS=input:b0003v046DpC52Fe0111-e0,1,2,4,k110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,11A,11B,11C,11D,11E,11F,r0,1,6,8,am4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="Logitech USB Receiver"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0"
PRODUCT=3/46d/c52f/111
PROP=0
REL=143
SEQNUM=1513
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=325550123
```

**Keyboard event**

```
UDEV  [325.555963] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.2/4-1.2:1.1/input/input16 (input)
ABS=100000000
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.2/4-1.2:1.1/input/input16
EV=1f
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_MODEL=USB_Receiver
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Receiver
ID_MODEL_ID=c52f
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_2_1_1
ID_REVISION=3000
ID_SERIAL=Logitech_USB_Receiver
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030102:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_VENDOR=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Logitech
ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
KEY=4837fff072ff32d bf54444600000000 1 20f908b17c000 677bfad9415fed 9ed68000004400 10000002
MODALIAS=input:b0003v046DpC52Fe0111-e0,1,2,3,4,k71,72,73,74,77,80,82,83,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8B,8C,8E,90,96,98,9B,9C,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,AB,AC,AD,AE,B0,B1,B2,B5,B6,CE,CF,D0,D1,D2,D4,D8,D9,DB,DF,E4,E7,E8,E9,EA,EB,F1,100,161,162,166,16A,16E,172,174,176,178,179,17A,17B,17C,17D,17F,180,182,183,185,188,189,18C,18D,18E,18F,190,191,192,193,195,198,199,19A,1A0,1A1,1A2,1A3,1A4,1A5,1A6,1A7,1A8,1A9,1AA,1AB,1AC,1AD,1AE,1B0,1B1,1B7,1BA,r6,a20,m4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="Logitech USB Receiver"
PHYS="usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input1"
PRODUCT=3/46d/c52f/111
PROP=0
REL=40
SEQNUM=1519
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=325514060
```

Answer (score 1):

So far what has worked for me is simply find the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules`.

Find this entry, and comment it out:

```
    # Logitech devices
    KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d",
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]", \
    RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"
```

It should look like this.

```
    # Logitech devices
    #KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", 
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]", \
    #  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p
```

Save the file, unplug, and replug the receiver, it works fine.

The only problem I can see is that this may be overwritten on updates. I have yet to spot a better solution.

Comment: You're very close. Copy your modified `/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules` file to `/etc/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules`: any rule files in `/etc/udev/rules.d` will *override* files with the same name in `/lib/udev/rules.d`. And the files in `/etc/udev/rules.d` won't be touched by updates, guaranteed.