# How to automatically run a script when I connect a bluetooth device?

Tags: scripting

I have a bluetooth headset and I need to execute a .sh file everytime I connect it to make it work. I don't want to troubleshoot this bug since I know there's already people looking into it.

But I'm interested on a way to run that .sh script every time I connect a bluetooth device. And, if it's possible, every time I connect a headset/this specific headset.

Answer (score 4):

Look into `udev` rules. See [the ArchWiki article on udev rules](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev#About_udev_rules) and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in/28577#28577) about running a script when a USB device is plugged in.

There are also already many questions on this site regarding bluetooth and udev rules.  See:

- [Making udev rule for bluetooth keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144417/making-udev-rule-for-bluetooth-keyboard)
- [udev rule for bluetooth device(logitec)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105585/udev-rule-for-bluetooth-devicelogitec?rq=1)

Comment: The +Run key in a Udev-Rule is not longer working under systemd.  `ps -p 1 -o comm=`

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked (ubuntu 22.04 on Raspberry PI 4):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Toggles headset connection
import dbus
from gi.repository import GLib
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

dev_id = '74_A3_4A_DF_BB_8A'

def signal_handler(*args, **kwargs):
  if (dev_id in kwargs['path']) & (args[0] == 'org.bluez.MediaControl1'):
    if args[1]['Connected']:
      print('connected')
    else:
      print('disconnected')

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
#register your signal callback
bus.add_signal_receiver(signal_handler,
                        bus_name='org.bluez',
                        interface_keyword='interface',
                        member_keyword='member',
                        path_keyword='path',
                        message_keyword='msg')
loop = GLib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

About how to automatically run this script on boot. When I first tried this with the systemd unit, it didn't work for me. The unit was started before device hci0 appeared. The working solution turned out to be adding the line:

```
ExecStartPre=hciconfig hci0 up
```

Here is an example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Служба управления phasetimer.
After=sound.target
After=bluetooth.target
 
[Service]
Type=simple
KillSignal=SIGINT
WorkingDirectory=/home/zenbooster/git/phasetimer
ExecStartPre=hciconfig hci0 up
ExecStart=python3 /home/zenbooster/git/phasetimer/guardian.py
Restart=on-failure
SyslogIdentifier=phasetimer-guardian
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStartSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Looks good, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would try this:

1. Open a shell (bash, sh, ksh) and type: `set -e`   (enables errorhandling)
2. Insert Your BT- device
3. Type: `echo $?`

You should get a number larger than 0, which is an errorcode. Depending on which shell you use, there might be set some environment variables:

- ERR=$?=Errorcode
- ERL=Linenumber if trap was detected in a script.
- $?=0 then there is no errorcode, and U dont need to read further.

Write a script, or test by hand:

```
trap 'ERR=$?;errorhandler' listofcodes
```

errorhandler is the script that decides what todo when any of the listofcodes occur.

The list could be 1 10 14 15 (17 18 ...) or just 1 number, the one you want to catch.

```
# script errorhandler
errorhandler(){
case $ERR in
    1)
#    here U can take action or perhaps just ignore
    return
    ;;
    *) 
#    action if errorcode was different from 1

    ;;


esac
}
```

You would place line 1-4 in `/etc/profile` or similar to make it systemwide.

In `/etc` there should be an `rc.d` or `init.d` containg start and stop scripts related to boot and change in runstate. There should be a scriptfile for your BT device, check it out, but don't change content unless ...

If the errorcode in line 2 is zero then you must dig deeper.